# Sorting List of Arrays by different elements using Java 8 lambdas

Tags: java, list, sorting, lambda, java-8

If I have a `List<String[]>` in which each `String[]` is as follows: {FirstName, LastName, Income, City} how would I go about using Java 8 lambdas to sort the List by a certain value such as income or first name?

Comment: Why don't you turn the `String[]` into an object, e.g. `Person`, and have the `Person` class implement Comparable?

Comment: Also if income is a number putting it in a string will make it not sortable (it will sort alphabetically).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a couple examples.  Replace x in the first two examples below with the index of the field you'd like to use for sorting.

```
Collections.sort(personList, (p1, p2) -> p1[x].compareTo(p2[x]));
```

or

```
personList.sort((p1, p2) -> p1[x].compareTo(p2[x]);
```

Also, I agree with @Robin Topper's comment.  **If lambdas are required** (and you wanted to sort by first name), you could use:

```
Collections.sort(personList, (p1, p2) -> p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName()));
```

or

```
personList.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName()));
```

Also consider using the comparable implementation from Robin's comment and a data-structure allowing sorting.

Comment: My suggested `Person` class would use getters and setters instead of public fields ;-)

Comment: Or `Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName)`.

Comment: Likewise, `Comparator.comparing(a -> a[x])` for the array case. In either case, `Comparator.comparing` ensures that both sides of the comparison use the same function, which avoids copy&paste errors and such alike.

Comment: Thank you it works wonderfully for the strings, is there any way I could parse the income element to an integer and sort it by that?

Comment: I actually managed to figure it out. I used  `Collections.sort(relative, (p1, p2) -> Integer.valueOf(p2[2]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p1[2])));`

Answer (score 2):

If you **can rely** on the order in this array, then as simple as:

```
List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "eugene", "test", "300", "LA" }, 
                              new String[] { "hunter", "test2", "25", "CA" });

 List<String[]> sorted = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s[2])))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    sorted.forEach(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
```

But the general advice to create an `Object` from those fields is much better.

Comment: You don't need to create a stream for sorting, e.g. `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> Long.parseLong(s[2])))`

Comment: @RobinTopper yup I know, the other answer shows that. thx anyway

Comment: `List.of(…)` requires Java 9. In Java 8, you have to stay with `Arrays.asList(…)`. But if you use `List.of`, you can’t use `List.sort`, so using a stream is justified.

Comment: It might be beneficial to use `Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s[2]))`, by the way, to avoid boxing overhead.